# BitLocker bde-repair: Repairing disk with bad sector with a consistent 512 offset apart. What is going on?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, recovery

I'm trying to repair a disk with a BitLocker encryption after sustaining a small fall (I guess it was bigger than it appeared).

I'm using bde-repair on windows 10. I get a lot of these type messages:

```
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000037
Failed to read sector at offset 1054367232. (0x00000017)
```

Interestingly, the offset between the bad sectors is exactly 512.

```
----Long sections where the sector is placed at an offset exactly 512 apart----

LOG ERROR: 0xc0000037
Failed to read sector at offset 1053051904. (0x00000017)
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000037
Failed to read sector at offset 1053052416. (0x00000017)
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000037
Failed to read sector at offset 1053052928. (0x00000017)
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000037
Failed to read sector at offset 1053053440. (0x00000017)
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000037
Failed to read sector at offset 1053053952. (0x00000017)
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000037
Failed to read sector at offset 1053054464. (0x00000017)
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000037
Failed to read sector at offset 1053054976. (0x00000017)
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000037
Failed to read sector at offset 1053055488. (0x00000017)
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000037
Failed to read sector at offset 1053056000. (0x00000017)
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000037
Failed to read sector at offset 1053056512. (0x00000017)
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000037

----Then it skips more than 512----

Failed to read sector at offset 1054359552. (0x00000017)
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000037
```

Note that the output pasted above is just a sample. In reality I have hundreds of such bad-sector entries.

What's the meaning of the consistent offset?

Comment: "What's the meaning of the consistent offset?" - What do you mean? I am shocked you are reading anything off that drive in it's current state.

Comment: We’ll, obviously the drive is damaged. Some quick research about the 512 increment suggests that what you are looking at is the BYTE offset, not the sector offset. Each sector is 512 bytes. Therefore you are looking at several consecutive sectors which are failing to be read. If the data on the drive is important you are making a critical mistake by trying to run recovery tools on the bad drive. Always, always, always clone the drive first as fast as possible with the proper tools which can handle bad sectors efficiently. One such tool is `ddrescue`. Then work on the clone.

Comment: Of course, if you'd had a backup, you could just bin this drive & restore to a new one...

Comment: @Appleoddity I'll do a clone as you suggest.